# Fill variable space beneath DIV with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Take the following scenario:

```
<div class="container" height="500px">
    <div>This div is responsive, so the height is variable</div>
    <div>This div need to fill the remaining vertical space in the container</div>
</div>
```

We no longer support IE8 or IE9 so flexbox is usable. I know how to achieve this using the current flexbox spec, but because Android (up to 4.4) is the new IE, and uses the 2009 spec, I'm not sure if, and how this can be done.

Any flexbox guru's have the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` on the container and `flex-direction:column`

`flex:1` on the last div.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 200px;
  /* shortened for demo */
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: pink;
}
div:last-child {
  background: lightblue;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>This div is responsive, so the height is variable</div>
  <div>This div need to fill the remaining vertical space in the container</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam accusamus eaque nihil veniam deleniti necessitatibus aliquid, earum unde veritatis expedita ullam neque ut vero quidem perspiciatis minima in quia quisquam aliquam, cupiditate enim impedit
    minus delectus, eum, doloribus. Hic iure esse, est autem cumque ullam odio beatae animi perspiciatis ad quibusdam nobis enim, libero adipisci</div>
  <div>This div need to fill the remaining vertical space in the container</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use legacy code for the 2009 spec. `flex-direction: column` maintains the vertical order of the items.

`flex: 1` which is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1 and flex-shrink: 1`, on the second child will expand it and avail the remaining height.

This is a very handy tool: [**Echoplex Flexyboxes**](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) to generate the legacy code.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}
.first {
  background: lightblue;
}
.second {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">This div is responsive, so the height is variable</div>
  <div class="second">This div need to fill the remaining vertical space in the container</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="second">This div need to fill the remaining vertical space in the container</div>
</div>
```